Failed to load magic database
I am quite new to cpp and its libraries, My aim is to find MIME type of a file so I am using magic library for it in cpp. and I want to make an executable which would be portable ie it should run on any machine whether or whether not the libmagic is present on that machine.
I statically linked  magic libraries to my program and generated its executable. the executable is running properly on my ubuntu machine but when I transferred it to  another vm(ubuntu) (where magic is not installed) and I tried to run the executable my magic database is not loading and I am getting the following errors
WARNING - Failed to load magic database. Cannot determine MIME type for file:
here is the function to find the mime type of a file
std::string mime_type(const std::string& filename) {
    magic_t cookie = magic_open(MAGIC_MIME_TYPE);

    if (cookie == nullptr) {
        logger.log(WARNING, "Failed to open libmagic. Cannot determine MIME type for file: '" + filename + "'");
        return "unknown";
    }

    if (magic_load(cookie, NULL) != 0) {
        logger.log(WARNING, "Failed to load magic database. Cannot determine MIME type for file: '" + filename + "'");
        magic_close(cookie);
        return "unknown";
    }

    std::string mimetype = magic_file(cookie, filename.c_str());
    // Close libmagic handle before returning
    magic_close(cookie);

    if (mimetype.empty()) {
        // logger.log(WARNING, "Failed to determine MIME type for file: '" + filename + "'");
        return "unknown";
    }
    // std::cout << mimetype << std::endl;
    return mimetype;
}

Please help
I was expecting my program to find the MIME type of the file

Why don't you use magic_error() so you can see why it fails? The idea when you validate function calls is not to just log that they didn't get called properly, but to also monitor errors and handle exceptions (if needed). Always use error checking functions along with whatever custom messages or custom logging method you have, else you'll spend days trying to find what black magic causes an error instead of having it written and solving the mystery in 5 seconds. Trust me, I learned that the hard way when I first started. Also, maybe validate filename is not empty as well, for good measure.

In your VM ubuntu you probably don't have the default magic database file. If you want to use your binary on a system that doesn't have libmagic-dev installed, you should at least provide  magic.mgc and set MAGIC env var to point to that file.
